# An unexpected error has occurred in expo developer tools after upgrading it to SDK 45 and reinstalling it after some errors

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I upgraded expo to SDK 45 after expo go app said it was not compatible. After that expo couldn't be found and I had to install it with yarn. After starting it this happened and it was also not working on mobile. Please help!!!

[I tried different browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZioZ2.png)